# Loading until Ajax Load

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have div into index.php ( wordpress ) .
Send number to page.php with jquery and return result with ajax into index.php

I Want Show Loading in Div ( Or Text Or image ) Until Ajax Loaded.

Here My Code :

```
<script>
myfunc = function()
{           
    $("#target").slideUp(400);
    $("#target").slideDown(400,"swing",function()
        {                           
            splittedURL=window.location.href.split("#");
            $.post('<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/page.php','state='+splittedURL[1],function(data,status)
            {
                $("#target").html(data);
            })      
        }
    );                          
}
</script>
```

Comment: I Want Show Loading Message in #target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
myfunc = function()
{   
    $('#target').html("my html here");
    $("#target").slideUp(400);
    $("#target").slideDown(400,"swing",function()
        {                           
            splittedURL=window.location.href.split("#");
            $.post('<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/page.php','state='+splittedURL[1],function(data,status)
            {
                $("#target").html(data);
            })      
        }
    );                          
}
</script>
```